# Airflow scheduler doesn't work for monthly jobs schedule

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am trying to schedule a monthly airflow job. I kept start date as

```
'start_date':datetime(2020,9,23),
```

which is the date for previous month(today's date); because of the 'start_date+schedule_interval' rule. I kept my schedule interval as :

```
 schedule_interval="20 9 23 * *"
```

By this logic job should run on 2020/23/10 9:23 UTC . But I don't know why it's not running or even creating an instance. I did everything right, kept start date to one month before and even tried with catchup= True. But it doesn't help.

Job is running if I try keeping the schedule as daily; ex:

```
start_date':airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1)
```

and schedule interval as:

```
schedule_interval="20 9 * * *"
```

and it works file. Ran a job today at 9.20 UTC.

Note: I have ran the job before manually so it has last execution date as something else. Can that be the problem . If so, how can I resolve it or will I have to create a new job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `schedul_interval` can cause problems and it's recommended to create a new DAG, see [Common Pitfalls on Apache Airflow Confluence](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62694614):

> When needing to change your start_date and schedule interval, change
> the name of the dag (a.k.a. dag_id) - I follow the convention :
> my_dag_v1, my_dag_v2, my_dag_v3, my_dag_v4, etc...
>
> - **Changing schedule
>   interval always requires changing the dag_id, because previously run
>   TaskInstances will not align with the new schedule interval**
> - Changing
>   start_date without changing schedule_interval is safe, but changing to
>   an earlier start_date will not create any new DagRuns for the time
>   between the new start_date and the old one, so tasks will not
>   automatically backfill to the new dates.  If you manually create
>   DagRuns, tasks will be scheduled, as long as the DagRun date is after
>   both the task start_date and the dag start_date.